# NextJS localeDetection not working when deployed to Netlify

Tags: next.js, localization, netlify

I have the following NextJS setup and localeDetection works like a charm on localhost, both on the dev server and when build.

But when deployed to Netlify the language detection is not working and the 307 redirect to /en never happens.

```
i18n: {
  locales: ['en', 'fr'],
  defaultLocale: 'fr',
  localeDetection: true,
},
```

Language header passed to the server:

```
Accept-Language: en
```

Comment: You're not using the [`NEXT_LOCALE` cookie](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/i18n-routing#leveraging-the-next_locale-cookie) anywhere in the app by any chance (I'd double check in the devtools)? That would override the `Accept-Language` header.

Comment: We don't use NEXT_LOCALE an i remove all cookies when tesing.

Comment: I'm running into the same issue. Have you found a solution @Pecata? I'm looking at Netlify redirects as a workaround.

Comment: @SilvestreHerrera unforunatelly not , i had a workaround but its not working great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking back in time it seems that the issue was related to missconfiguratuon in CloudFlare.